# share IndexedDB between iOS PWA and safari

Tags: ios, safari, indexeddb, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to share IndexedDB stores and data between a progressive web app (PWA) and stand-alone Safari on iOS? If so, what steps do I need to take to share the stores/data?

My use case is that I have a would-be PWA that uses third party authentication. The normal behavior is that when navigating to the third party authentication page, the PWA automatically opens the page in a new Safari window since it is out of scope. I would like to save the authentication token in IndexedDB from this Safari instance, open my PWA, and then load the token from IndexedDB in my PWA.

I have tested this implementation. It works fine (ie I can read the token from IndexedDB) in Safari standalone, but when I navigate back to my PWA and attempt to read the data, it doesn't exist. This suggests that the stores cannot be shared, but I am looking for a more definitive answer. I find no indication one way or the other in internet searches.

Note: local storage, session storage, and cookies are not shared between Safari and PWAs on iOS, so those solutions do not work which necessitated the use of IndexedDB

Comment: indexedDB is local storage

Comment: It can be shared between Chrome and pwa. Sadly, not with Safari though. Ideally one can use the answer proposed below of using a pop up instead.

Comment: Also just wondering if there's a way of authenticating using Ajax call instead of toggling between separate pages. Will try sometime soon and revert if poss.

Comment: @SaurabhRajpal, that is not possible

Comment: @digiplant I have the same issue. Did you figure this out yet?

Comment: @Wonka It is not possible to share the indexedDB instance or any other type of local storage. I solved my specific problem by creating a native java authentication function and deployed it in a AWS Lambda function behind a REST API endpoint.

Comment: there is a workaround check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669966/how-to-maintain-login-status-in-a-pwa-initially-loaded-via-safari-14-ios-14

Comment: hellow there is solved? 2021 say hi

Answer (score 0):

Rather than opening a new tab, you can use a pop up, like how it has been beautifully explained [here](https://medium.com/@jonnykalambay/progressive-web-apps-with-oauth-dont-repeat-my-mistake-16a4063ce113) with example and source code.
The key idea used here is  `window.postMessage`, which allows windows and frames to send data across domains to one another.

Comment: This solution does not work for an installed PWA in iOS.