# How to share cacheStorage between Safari and PWA (Standalone mode) in iPadOS 14?

Tags: safari, progressive-web-apps, ipados, cachestorage

I am trying to share data between Safari and a PWA/Standalone mode "Add to Homescreen" app in iPadOS 14 (not iOS) using cacheStorage.

I tried [Pooya Estakhri's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136388/12398796) and it worked on iOS 14, but the same code did not work for iPadOS 14, even though the reference to [Firt](https://firt.dev/ios-14/#storage-shared-with-safari) implies that cacheStorage should operate the same for iOS and iPadOS. It appears on iPadOS using `caches.open("auth")` that Safari and the PWA have separate cacheStorage.

Has anyone worked with this on iPadOS?